# How to add logger values to testng report?

Tags: selenium, junit, testng

I have selenium testcase for compare two reports page, at the end of test i am receiving either pass or fail only.But additionally i need the values which is used for comparison.How can I achieve this? 
Thanks,
Masilamani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reporter.log](http://testng.org/doclava/reference/org/testng/Reporter.html) can be used to log messages in the html report. It additionally gives you a argument to log to standard console apart from logging in report.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
 I have used Reporter.log, But the result in mail like a String.I need to be html table format. SO that users can see the values from 2 different places .anything can help me on this?

Comment: I didn't get your expectation.  You want the results to be in an html file?  Doesn't the standard index.html report that testng generates, satisfy your usecase?

Comment: Hi, My requirement : Compare 2 reports say for example report A and report B, and send the test result to users.Either pass or fail. Done: 
=====
As per your suggestion i have used Reporter.log, now i am getting logs like MethodOne was failed , value from ReportA is"xxxxx" value from ReportB is "yyyy", 
Expecting:
the above is like String , I Feel to present it as Table format bcoz i have so many pair of values , Is there way to create my logs in html format or can i update index.html file to include this value?